# Haskell rules for selecting between type instances for Int, Double and Integer

Tags: haskell

I would like to know what are the rules used by Haskell to always decide for the Integer instance instead of the others when evaluating in GHCi the expression `1 .+. 2`:

```
import Debug.Trace

class MyFuns a where
    (.+.) :: a →  a →  a

instance MyFuns Double where
    x .+. y = trace "Double " $ x + y

instance MyFuns Integer where
    x .+. y = trace "Integer " $ x + y

instance MyFuns Int where 
    x .+. y = trace "Int " $ x + y
```

**EDIT**: if I add the following code at the end of the file

```
main = do
   let x = 1 .+. 2
   print x
```

why do I get this error?

```
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal ‘1’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include x :: a0 (bound at fun2.hs:19:7)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
  instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  ...plus three others
In the first argument of ‘(.+.)’, namely ‘1’
In the expression: 1 .+. 2
In an equation for ‘x’: x = 1 .+. 2
```

Yet, if I load the file at GHCi prompt without the `main = ...`, and then type `1 .+. 2`, GHCi prints `3` as expected. Why this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [section 4.3.4 in the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4). When Haskell reads a literal that looks integral (no decimal component), the type is (unless more specifically inferred) `Num a => a`. The moment it *needs* to choose a type, it uses the defaulting rules, and normally the default is `Integer`. When a literal has a decimal component, it is `Fractional a => a`, which is normally defaulted to `Double`.

By using a `default` top-level declaration, you can change these settings, e.g.:

```
default (Int, Float)
```

would default `Num` to `Int` and `Fractional` to `Float` (because `Int` is not `Fractional`). *Note that the effect of this statement is local to the module in which it is declared.*

The default statement has the following effect (quoting the report):

> Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable’s classes. It is a static error if no such type is found.

The -XExtendedDefaultRules GHC flag has additional effects, see [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).

---

**Edit**

As for your error, the source is the following statement, which is in the [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) and in different wording in section 4.3.4 of the report:

> However, it is tiresome for the user to have to specify the type, so GHCi extends Haskell's type-defaulting rules (Section 4.3.4 of the Haskell 2010 Report) as follows. The standard rules take each group of constraints (C1 a, C2 a, ..., Cn a) for each type variable a, and defaults the type variable if
>
> 1. The type variable a appears in no other constraints
> 2. **All the classes Ci are standard.**
> 3. At least one of the classes Ci is numeric.

Where I intentionally put focus on the second bullet. Because you're using `.+.`, one of the classes of the numbers is `MyFuns` - which is not a class from the Prelude or the standard library, so it is not a "standard" class. Luckily, the text continues as follows:

> At the GHCi prompt, or with GHC if the -XExtendedDefaultRules flag is given, the following additional differences apply:
>
> - **Rule 2 above is relaxed thus: All of the classes Ci are single-parameter type classes.**
> - Rule 3 above is relaxed this: At least one of the classes Ci is numeric, or is Show, Eq, or Ord.
> - The unit type () is added to the start of the standard list of types which are tried when doing type defaulting.

In conclusion, if you use the `ExtendedDefaultRules` flag (which as you can see is active in GHCi by default), your code will compile just fine also with your custom class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Debug.Trace

default (Int, Float, Double)

class MyFuns a where
    (.+.) :: a -> a -> a

instance MyFuns Double where
    x .+. y = trace "Double " $ x + y

instance MyFuns Integer where
    x .+. y = trace "Integer " $ x + y

instance MyFuns Int where
    x .+. y = trace "Int " $ x + y

main = do
   print $ 1 .+. 2 -- Interpreted as Int
```

Note that in this example `1.0 .+. 2.0` is interpreted as double, while `1.0 + 2.0` is interpreted as float: this is because there is no `MyFuns` instance for Float, so its entry in the `default` list is skipped.

Comment: I have added `default (Int, Float)` and still don't get the Int instance called, so the solution must be something else. I am using GHCi 7.8.3

Comment: Even if I disable the default rules for Num by doing `default ()` the Integer instance still gets called.

Comment: I think what is happening is that GHCi doesn't take into account the default statement in your source file (the report states that the effect of the `default` statement is limited to the module). If I load a module with your source and type `5 .+. 9` I get an `Integer`. After that I type `default (Int, Float)` (in ghci) and then `5 .+. 9` again, then I get an `Int`. So it works for me.

Comment: I tested and got the same behavior as you did. This is probably then a bug in GHCi ...

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, the behavior is as specified in the report.

Comment: So I have to read the report to understand the different behaviors between compiled and interpreted modes of Haskell?

Comment: The issue you encountered is not really a difference between the compiled and interpreted mode. The `default` statement is *local to the module in which it is defined* - when you load the module you are not in this local environment. It doesn't matter whether you load the module from ghci, or from inside another module. If you put your printing statement in a main function inside the source file the `default` setting will be taken into account (because then you are in the local environment).

Comment: OK, I understand now. But I don't think that was a good choice by Haskell's designers. It may cause confusion having different defaults in different modules.

Comment: @mljrg It would probably be *more* confusing if the default types suddenly changed just because you loaded some 3rd party module...

Comment: You said "If you put your printing statement in a main function inside the source file the default setting ..." will work. I have done it and got the above error when loading the file. I only tested what you suggested know, and it did not work. That's why I reopened the question. Can you please help?

Comment: Right, I didn't see your edit. See my updated answer.

Comment: Aaarrgghhh! Different contexts, different default behaviors! This is a nightmare for those trying to enter Haskell. GHCi and GHC defaults or anything else should be consistent. I have lost hours chasing this ... Two questions: 1) How can I ask GHCi to print the defaults it is using? 2) How can I invoke GHCi (or GHC) so that all behaviors are the same at the prompt or when loading code from files?

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions and I can't find them either. Maybe you can open a separate question for this, I would also be interested in the answers.