# How does `succ` with a numeric literal work?

Tags: haskell, ghc

```
λ> succ 5
6
λ> :t succ 5
succ 5 :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
```

How does this work? Since the literal is polymorphic, what is the instance that is being picked? I suspect it’s `Integer` but why exactly?

My first theory was that the default implementation of `succ` might come into play (I have no idea *why* this would happen though), but, no, it’s not the case as it would not be working correctly:

```
λ> :t succ (10^20)
succ (10^20) :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
λ> succ (10^20)
100000000000000000001
λ> 
λ> let test = toEnum . (+1) . fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> a
λ> :t test (10^20)
test (10^20) :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
λ> test (10^20)
7766279631452241921
```

So, again, I’m pretty sure it’s the instance for `Integer`. But why?

Comment: It's because of the defaulting rules. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549948/haskell-rules-for-selecting-between-type-instances-for-int-double-and-integer/32550216#32550216)

Comment: In general, the type is inferred from the *context* in which the result is used. Add it to the result of `length []` to see it magically change.  The defaulting rules kick in only when the context does not give enough information.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden Yes, of course you are right, it’s just defaulting. What probably confused me is that GHCi keeps showing the polymorphic type.

Comment: That's explained easily: the command `:t some-expr` is treated differently than just `some-expr`.   In the first case no defaulting is performed, in the latter defaulting **must** be performed, because GHCi has to actually produce a value in order to print it and values must have a monomorphic type. To see the type that is actually used use `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` and `:set +t`.  Then when evaluating `succ 5` it will also display `it :: Integer`.  Note however that you probably don't want to keep the monomorphism restriction enabled in GHCi.